# Installing libjpeg62-dev for using modprobe bcm2835-v4l

Tags: camera, raspicam, packages

I need to use the Raspberry Pi camera with OpenCV. For that, I have to run `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l`. But for that, I need to install it. I did it on another RPi a while ago, but I forgot the whole procedure.

I'm now following a post from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62364) but I got a problem installing `libjpeg62-dev` :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg62-dev : Depends: libjpeg62 (= 1:6b2-2)
```

Then I followed [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168424/how-to-install-libjpeg62-dev-on-raspberry-pi) and I added `deb [trusted=yes] http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (I should specify `[trusted=yes]` otherwise the protection prevented me to use that repository). But even after the update, I was not able to install the package (same error).

I also tried to installed `libjpeg62` (without dev) myself but it said it will remove 140 (!) packages, which looks important, so I aborted it.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  adwaita-icon-theme agnostics alacarte arandr chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n desktop-base dillo ffmpeg fswebcam galculator geany giblib1
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gnome-icon-theme gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-standard gpicview gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gtk-update-icon-cache gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-clearlookspix gtk2-engines-pixbuf gtk2-engines-pixflat gvfs-backends
  libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libchromaprint1 libcupsfilters1 libdjvulibre21 libfm-gtk4 libfm-modules libgd3
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgphoto2-6 libgs9 libgtk-3-0 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libimlib2 libindicator3-7 libjpeg62-turbo
  libkeybinder0 libnotify4 libobrender32v5 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpoppler82 libqt5gui5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
  librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsdl-image1.2 libspandsp2 libspectre1 libtiff5 libunique-1.0-0 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvte-2.91-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwnck22 libzbar0 lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter lxappearance lxappearance-obconf lxde lxde-core lxhotkey-gtk lxinput lxpanel lxplug-bluetooth
  lxplug-cputemp lxplug-ejecter lxplug-magnifier lxplug-network lxplug-ptbatt lxplug-volume lxpolkit lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxsession-logout
  lxtask lxterminal mousepad obconf omxplayer openbox openbox-lxde-session pcmanfm pi-greeter pi-package pi-package-data pi-package-session piclone
  pipanel pishutdown piwiz pixflat-icons python-gtk2 python-pil python-pygame python-sense-hat python3-pgzero python3-pil python3-pygame python3-sense-hat
  qpdfview qpdfview-djvu-plugin qpdfview-ps-plugin qpdfview-translations qt5-gtk-platformtheme qt5-style-plugins qt5ct raspberrypi-ui-mods rc-gui
  rp-bookshelf rp-prefapps rpi-chromium-mods scrot sense-hat v4l-utils vlc vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-skins2 xarchiver
  zenity
```

Finally, I checked with aptitude, and got that answer:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg62-turbo : Conflicts: libjpeg62 but 1:6b2-2 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libjpeg62 [Not Installed]
2)     libjpeg62-dev [Not Installed]
```

So, it looks like there is a conflict with `libjpeg62-turbo`, I checked to uninstall it, but again it will remove many packages, hence I aborted it again.

So, now I am a bit lost and I don't know what to do. What should I do to install that package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you really using `wheezy`?

Comment: I followed one post that said the package libjpeg62-dev had been removed from the current release and I should use an old one. But I am not familiar with that, so I understood it's not really good, and I planed to remove ```wheezy``` when I manage to install my package.

Comment: well, following an 8 year old guide is probably not helping - have you tried installing libjpeg62-turbo-dev?

Comment: or maybe `modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`

Comment: having said that `bcm2835-v4l2` seems to be loaded at boot anyway

Comment: I tried ```modprobe bcm2835-v4l2```, at first it didn't work, but the I realised that I stupidly forget to enable camera in raspi-config ^^'
So, now it works perfectly! Thanks for your helpful remarks!

Comment: And I installed the libjpeg62-turbo-dev as you recommended

Answer (score 0):

As it was proposed in a comment, I installed `libjpeg62-turbo-dev`, and also I activated the camera in `raspi-config` and now it works.